# Twentyseveteen Child Theme - Mobile Menu JavaScript doesn't trigger on every page

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, menu, themes

I built a Child Theme using Twentyseventeen as a template. I used the  CSS from theme and worked on the Custom CSS for the website for a while.

I've noticed today that the **strong text**mobile menu expands only on the homepage.**strong text** When I try other pages, mobile menu doesn't trigger the JQuery event, so it doesn't show the menu at all. If anyone could help me out with the code.

Here is the link to the production website:

http://bpositive.heistdc.com

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is too broad of a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - try and get to the root of the problem. Where is the JS? Are you sure it is included on every page? Do the pages share different headers? Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Pages do not have different headers, hence the confusion. JS is added in the head of every page through header.php in the 2017 theme root. @sheriffderek

Comment: JS comes provided with the theme so I didn't customize anything in the code, actually used the functional code from the parent theme. When I switch back to the **twentyseventeen** my menu works just fine. @sheriffderek